# Show the 8 bits of a byte in PHP

Tags: php, binary

I was wondering if there is a easy way to display the 8 bits of a byte(or char) in PHP.

For example for ASCII encoding the character '0' should return 0011 0000

Thanks for your input!

Comment: a combination of ord() - for characters - and decbin()

Comment: @MarkBaker decbin, dechex is for hex data...

Comment: @bwoebi - already corrected thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
$bin = decbin(ord($char));
$bin = str_pad($bin, 8, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, exactly what I needed. Thanks! The function to handle a whole string which someone posted and removed was nice too.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) Could you mark it as answered if you believe it is :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [bitwise operators for that](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
$a='C';
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
  var_dump((ord($a) & (1<<$i))>>$i);
}
```

Output:

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

One more solution, this includes space between 4 digits:

```
$char = 0;
echo chunk_split(sprintf('%08b', ord($char)), 4, ' ');
```